# How to read binary files in a string sequence of 1 and 0?

Tags: java, file, binaryfiles

I've created a Huffman coding algorithm, and then I wrote binary code in `String` and put it in binary file using `FileOutputStream` and `DataOutputStream`.

But now I cant understand how to read it? I need to get 1 and 0 sequence from binary file.

There is no method like `.readString()` in `DataInputStream`

```
try{
    FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
    fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().add(new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("Binary", "*.bin"));
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileChooser.showSaveDialog(window));
    DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
    outputStream.writeChars(Main.string_ready_encode);
}catch (IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

`Main.string_ready_encode` contains ready sequence

Comment: Please show your pertinent code so we can see *exactly* what your code is doing rather than what you think it may be doing. Let's not have to guess at a potential solution.

Comment: What do you mean you wrote the binary code in a string? Does that mean the file is full of the characters `'1'` and `'0'`, or did you actually write out bit sequences? in other words, did you convert the string into the bytes corresponding to the 1s and 0s?

Comment: No, its just a string sequence of 1 and 0, and then put it into .bin file

Comment: Please follow the java naming conventions and name variables camelCase. So `string_ready_encode` should become `stringReadyEncode`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your writing code is that you have specified no file format. We now can only read the file if we know how many bytes it has. If you do know that, you can read it by doing the following:

```
try (DataInputStream stream = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(f))) {
    byte[] bytes = new byte[NUMBER_OF_BYTES];
    stream.read(bytes);
    String content = new String(bytes);
    System.out.println(content);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But I would actually advise you to rewrite you file with some known file format, like so:

```
try (Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(f), Charsets.UTF_8)) {
    writer.write(Main.stringReadyEncode, 0, Main.stringReadyEncode.length());
} catch (IOException x) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And read it like you would read any other file:

```
try (BufferedReader r = Files.newBufferedReader(f.toPath(), Charsets.UTF_8)) {
    String line;
    while((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
        // do whatever you want with line
        System.out.println(line);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Just make sure to replace `Charsets.UTF_8` with whatever encoding you used while writing to the file.

Comment: I dont need to read every bit singly, can I read one line into string?

Comment: I got **java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1** in cycle

Comment: Then you used the wrong `Charset`. You need to switch `Charsets.UTF_8` for the `Charset` you used when writing..

Comment: @LonelyNeuron: good luck getting a reply. I've been waiting 30 minutes for the OP to show one speck of code.

Comment: Well, I dont know...I just used **FileOutputStream** and **DataOutputStream** and never specify coding

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels did it ;D

Comment: @LonelyNeuron I need to write it binary. The way you discribed - I did it before, but I need my output file to be smaller then original